# esp-idf build flash fails when esp32 when component #includes esp_types.h found in newlib/ not esp32/

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, esp32

On Mac osX I followed the [getting started guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/get-started/index.html) and can't get past `make flash` in the hello_world example project.

All of the code I am using is cloned straight from this repo: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf

I execute `make clean` (which works) and `make flash` from my copy of the hello_world example in `~/esp/hello_world/` and make flash gives this fatal error:

```
In file included from /Users/me/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include/esp32/rom/uart.h:18:0,
  from /Users/me/esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader_support/src/bootloader_clock.c:14:
/Users/me/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include/esp_types.h:19:23:fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The offending line in `esp-idf/components/esp_common/include/esp_types.h` is: `#include <sys/cdefs.h>`

There is a file in

`.../esp-idf/components/newlib/include/sys/cdefs.h`
but not in
`.../esp-idf/components/esp32/include/sys/cdefs.h`

I have confirmed this as the problem by creating a soft link:

```
cd ~/esp/esp-idf/components/esp32/include
ln -s ~/esp/esp-idf/components/newlib/include/sys sys
```

after which the build moves on to the next similar problem with

`esp32/include/sys/cdefs.h:43:36: fatal error: machine/_default_types.h: No such file or directory`

I have investigated several options to add the newlib/include directory to the list of system directories that are searched for #include  directives, including adding -I options to the command line, but I can't work out the 'proper' way to do it, as I don't want to be modifying any files in the repository  https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf

I hope this is something obvious. I have not dealt with make files since I was at Uni, and I feel like I might have to use a `long int` to store how many years ago that was.

Comment: The guide you've linked does not appear to instruct you to run `make` directly at any point.  Do you have the same problem if you follow its instructions to use the `idf.py` script to configure, build, and flash your project?

Comment: Thanks JohnBollinger - you may be onto somwthing - this (for v3.2.2) https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v3.2.2/get-started/index.html#build-and-flash told me to run make build and I linked to (v latest) https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/get-started/index.html Let me see if that fixes it

Comment: I see there is some documentation about installing cmake: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v3.2.2/get-started-cmake/macos-setup.html Let me see if that works

Comment: @JohnBollinger John Bollinger do you want to make that an answer and I can accept it? I was confused between two sets of instructions, but when I used your suggested idf.py instead of make, it did work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the getting started guide to which you linked instructs you to use a Python script named `idf.py` to configure, build, and flash esp32 projects (after several other steps for installing the framework and supporting tools).  Nowhere does the guide describe running `make` directly, though it seems that may constitute a change from earlier versions.

Although it seems likely that there are other alternatives, the most straightforward approach would be to follow the guide and use the `idf.py` script as it describes.